# Using Dynamic Table Dropdown to Disable Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just need some clarification with the JQuery/JavaScript syntax.

```
for (var i=0;i<tableb.rows.length;i++){
    var roway = tableb.rows[i];
    if($(roway).find("input[id='location']")=='rr'){
        alert("eeee");
       }
   }
```

The above isn't working, and I'm not too certain how to specify when the "rr" value is selected in the dropdown with the location id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "rr"? You're doing a comparison of a string against a jQuery element. What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Try `if($(roway).find('input[id="location"]').val() == 'rr'){}`

Comment: Also, if you're using a `<select>` be aware it's not an `<input>`.

Comment: Andrew's answer makes sense, but it unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Figured it out; as Alex pointed out, <select> isn't an <input>, so just swapping the input[id=... to select[id=... worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can I see your html?

Why do you have multiple id's in the first place? Anyways

```
for (var i=0;i<tableb.rows.length;i++){
    var roway = tableb.rows[i];
    if($(roway).find("input#location").val()=='rr'){
        alert("eeee");
       }
   }
```

In case you have only 1 input with that ID then a cleaner way is

```
if($("input#location") && ("input#location").val() == 'rr') {
    alert('eeee');
}
```